# How do I change my image width to be twice the size of the screen's width?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I want my image's height to be the height of the display and the width of two screen widths, I tried this way, but the image width doesn't change.

```
 length = display.actualContentWidth * 2

 local image = display.newImage("icon.png",display.contentCenterX,display.contentCenterY)
       image.width = length
       image.height = display.actualContentHeight
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the manual properties width and height give the original image size. So changing their values will most likely not resize the image.

You can use the `scale` function to resize the display object to the desired dimension once you've calculated the scale factors.